# why is my css animation not staying in the same place?

Tags: css, css-animations

When my page is loading, the logo animation starts in the bottom right corner of the screen, even though my logo element is positioned absolute. I really don't understand why this is happening and what to do about it.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="intro position-relative">
    <header class="company-name border border-5 p-2 p-sm-4 position-absolute start-50 translate-middle">
        <h1 class="lh-1">BAKKES</h1>
        <h2 class="lh-1">herenkappers en baardkwekers</h2>
    </header>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .company-name {
        top: 45%;
        animation: fade-names 1s linear forwards;
        animation-delay: 0.5s;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    @keyframes fade-names {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: scale(0.95);
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
```

Here's a link so you can see what happens: https://amazing-austin-69ee4a.netlify.app/

Comment: I think your library (bootstrap I guess) is giving you trouble somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do these codes.

I looked at your website.

```
.intro .company-name {

top:45%; // remove this

}

.start-50 {
    left: 50% !important; // remove this
}
.translate-middle {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important; // remove this
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important; // remove this
}

.intro {
    display: flex; // add this
    justify-content: center; // add this
    align-items: center; // add this
}
```

Comment: Yeah apparently it does work with flexbox, even though I still don't understand why it doesn't work with position. Anyway, thanks a lot!